# chrome initialize sandbox error

Tags: ubuntu

I'm running the command `google-chrome` in the terminal- ubuntu 14.04. but i'm getting the below error

```
ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(301)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process
```

chrome is also not working.